# Is it possible to write a function that will generate multiple graphs using ggplot?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to write a function that will generate multiple histograms (one for each level of a factor) using ggplot.

For the data set that I am using, I created a matrix of plots using `facet_wrap`, but I have 15 levels for my factor, and the counts for each level vary greatly for each bin, so the matrix of histograms wasn't very useful because I am forced to view each histogram on the same scale (e.g., one level had a max count of ~4,000, while another level only had a max count ~100).

Below is what I am trying to accomplish using the `iris` dataset as an example.

```
data(iris)
library(tidyverse)

histo_func = function(df){
  species_list = unique(df$Species) #create a vector of levels for Species
  for (i in seq_along(species_list)) {
    species_plot = ggplot(subset(df, df$Species==species_list[i]),
              aes(Sepal.Length)) +
              geom_histogram()
  }
}

species_hist = histo_func(df = iris)

 species_hist
NULL
```

After running the function, I call `species_hist` and get NULL.

The function itself works - if I step through using `debugonce()`, I can call `species_plot` and get the histogram for whichever `i` the loop has cycled through at that point.

What I want (if possible) is to store the histograms in `species_hist` and be able to output all the histograms in succession upon calling `species_hist`.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Use `print(ggplot(subset(df, df$Species == species_list[i]), aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram())` inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue with your code, "species_plot" is overwritten with each iteration of the loop. You will either need to use the print statement as mentioned in the above comment or store the object in a list.
Also, you are not clearly defining the variable to return from the function.

```
histo_func = function(df){
  species_plot=list()
  species_list = unique(df$Species) #create a vector of levels for Species
  for (i in seq_along(species_list)) {
    species_plot[[i]] = ggplot(subset(df, df$Species==species_list[i]),
                          aes(Sepal.Length)) +
      geom_histogram()
  }
  names(species_plot) = species_list
  species_plot
}

species_hist = histo_func(df = iris)

species_hist
```

The above codes stores each plot as an object in a list, then names the list elements with the species name and then returns the entire structure back to the calling variable.

Comment: @d.b 's solution of adding a `print` call is the simplest solution. Being new to R, I forgot about the fact that the loop would simply overwrite my graph after each iteration.
@DaveT 's solution works better if the desired outcome is to store the plots.